# RSpec 3 Error undefined method `get' in request test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, request, rspec3

After migration on RSpec 3 request test fails.
Here is my test

```
describe 'GET /api/v1/activities' do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }

    subject { json['activities'] }

   context 'when not authenticated' do
      let(:token) { user.authentication_token }
      let(:email) { 'unregistered.user@mail.com' }
      before :each do
        get '/api/v1/activities', {}, {token: token, email: email}
      end
      it { expect(response).to_not be_success }
    end
end
```

Here is rspec log

```
Activities GET /api/v1/activities when not authenticated 
     Failure/Error: get '/api/v1/activities', {}, {token: token, email: email}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Activities::GETApiV1Activities::WhenNotAuthenticated:0x0000000becfaf8>
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, migration to RSpec3 was the cause of this issue. 
I'd resolved it by migrating to RSpec 2.99.0 and I received a hint to add this code to my spec_helper

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Now it works. Hurray!

Answer (score 1):

I already had `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` set, but we still used the capybara feature syntax here, which probably sets the type to feature. Once I changed `feature` to `describe`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add helper to request specs. In `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request
```

Also i assume that you have `type: :request` in you spec definition.

Comment: I have this string in `spec_helper` `config.include Requests::JsonHelpers, type: :request`, is it not the same? Also I already find solution that help me but I haven't enough reputation for post it at the same time. How do you think my and your solutions are relative?